# Find the last row with zero value in a range using formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently looking for a formula to return the no. of the row where I can find the last zero value in a 1-column range.

Example :

- 0
- 0
- 0
- 28
- 28
- 28
- 28
- 0
- 28

Considering rows above, I would like to find a formula that would return 8 (no. of the row) because it's the last row with a zero value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=MAX((A:A<>"")*(A:A=0)*ROW(A:A))
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually it returns the row of the first zero value in the range, and I would like to get the row of the last zero value ;-)

Comment: @Christophe, really?

Comment: Mmm I may be wrong, could you have a look on it there : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o4urXcJBtATadAdZgdXli5nlvT6pI1nCmzK1wNUbH6E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The problem is it's array entered in Excel, other than Excel O365. In GS you need to set `ARRAYFORMULA`

Comment: Thanks a lot ;-) I didn't expect get a answer as quickly

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(MAX(IF((A:A=0)*(A:A<>""); ROW(A:A); )))
```

[image]